# What does this line all mean?

Tags: meaning, translation, anime

please explain what this means its a line by Ojousama character from an anime「[お慕い申しております！どうしても、この気持ちをお伝えしたくて！もしよかったら、わたくしと永遠の契りを あぁー私 (わたくし) ったら、もう何を言ってるんでしょうか？]。

Comment: "I really admire you! I just really wanted to let you know my feelings! If it's not too much to ask, would you consider spending the rest of your life with- oh my, what am I saying?" I assume that 永遠の契り here refers to marriage, but maybe somebody else can weigh in with their own interpretation here.

Comment: FYI, [translation request are off-topic](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/1628).  Please edit your question to show your research efforts, and indicate what specifically is confusing to you.  Otherwise the question will be closed.

Comment: @Boolicious please tell me what all of it means I mean explain what that line was all about

Answer (score 2):

Aside from vocabulary, an analysis of the quote evokes a number of literary conventions, which find their source in traditional Japanese culture.

1. This seems to be a standard manga or dorama style declaration of the speaker's feelings for another person お慕い申しております (the sentiment) and 気持ちをお伝えしたくて (the confirmation of the speaker's desire to convey said sentiment)
2. Request -- if the other person would agree もしよかったら -- for "the person's hand in marriage", since official documents are traditionally exchanged, as in a contract or, at least, here, a formal vow, an "eternal promise", i.e. 永遠の契り (which in a different context may connote a more spiritual, even religious commitment).
3. This declaration/request/"confession" (depending on context) is followed by another standard leitmotif found in manga/dorama, whereby the declaration itself is considered (by the possibly embarrassed speaker -- and perhaps in light of social norms) as an impulsive, or even premature, unexpected revelation of the speaker's private sentiments, even a betrayal of the speaker's own sense of dignity. [Abrupt interruption of declaration/request] あぁー 私 (わたくし)ったら、もう何を言ってるんでしょうか？

Comment: sorry its from a scene I can't understand so if you don't mind I want to discuss about it with you.Following your reply I'II ask this question: Did she reject him?

Comment: @DanielRigg I would say she didn't.

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth well I am confused about it and I need to be clear over it if you would explain it please

Comment: @DanielRigg It seems obvious to me if I read their answer. What are you confused about?

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth as I asked if it was a rejection but as you said that you would say she didn't but if she didn't then why she said this [あぁー私 (わたくし) ったら、もう何を言ってるんでしょうか？]。

Comment: @DanielRigg I'm not sure how it could be interpreted otherly, but it sounds to me that she becomes suddenly embarassed that it'd be unladylike to express such an explicit sentiment. But that means what she said before is her true feeling.

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth but its not a rejection?

Comment: @DanielRigg If "rejection" means a declaration that she doesn't love the hearer, no.

Comment: @DanielRigg can you provide a title, volume/episode number and a web link (plus reference, page number or if video a time stamp).